# How can I make a menu bar like in the tasm EDIT command

Tags: assembly, tasm

I want to create a text editor file using TASM. (For those who ask questions why I want to create this is because it's for academic purposes.)
What I have done so far is make an editable text. What I want to make is how can I make a menu bar that is like in the EDIT command of TASM. I appreciate it if you put some references.

This is the code I have done so far:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK

.DATA
CURSOR_X DB 0
CURSOR_Y DB 0

.CODE 
START: 
MOV AX,@DATA ;SET-UP DS TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS OUR DATA 
MOV DS,AX 
;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 10H, SERVICE 06H TO SCROLL WINDOW UP 
;THIS CREATES A CLEAR SCREEN EFFECT 
;ALSO SET-UP COLORS (BLUE BACKGROUND & RED TEXT) 
MOV AX,0600H 
MOV BH,1CH 
MOV CX,0 
MOV DX,184FH 
INT 10H 

SET_CURSOR: 
;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 10H, SERVICE 02H TO POSITION CURSOR 
MOV AH,02H 
MOV DL,CURSOR_X 
MOV DH,CURSOR_Y 
MOV BH,0 
INT 10H 

READ_KEY: 
;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 16H, SERVICE 00H TO READ KEYBOARD 
;(RETURNS ASCII CODE IN AL) 
MOV AH,0 
INT 16H

CMP AL, 1BH
JE EXIT

CMP AL, 08H
JE BACKSPACE 

;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 10H, SERVICE 0AH TO PRINT CHARACTER 
;AT CURRENT CURSOR POSITION 
MOV AH,0AH 
MOV CX,1 
MOV BH,0 
INT 10H 

CMP DL, 39
JE MOVE_DOWN

INC CURSOR_X
CMP DL, 39
JL SET_CURSOR

MOVE_DOWN: 

CMP DH, 9
JE READ_KEY

MOV CURSOR_X, 0
INC CURSOR_Y
CMP DH, 9
JL SET_CURSOR

BACKSPACE: 

CMP CURSOR_X, 0
JE MOVE_UP

DEC CURSOR_X
JMP ERASE

MOVE_UP: 

CMP CURSOR_Y, 0
JE READ_KEY

MOV CURSOR_X, 39
DEC CURSOR_Y
JMP ERASE
ERASE: 
;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 10H, SERVICE 02H TO POSITION CURSOR 
MOV AH,02H 
MOV DL,CURSOR_X 
MOV DH,CURSOR_Y 
MOV BH,0 
INT 10H 
;USE BIOS INTERRUPT 10H, SERVICE 0AH TO PRINT WHITESPACE 
;AT CURRENT CURSOR POSITION (ERASE) 
MOV AH,0AH 
MOV AL,WS 
MOV CX,1 
INT 10H 
JMP READ_KEY 
EXIT: 
;USE DOS INTERRUPT 21H, SERVICE 4CH TO EXIT PROGRAM 
MOV AX,4C00H 
INT 21H 

END START ;TELL ASSEMBLER TO FINISH
```

Now this is what I want to make:
[image: Menu Bar]

Comment: That looks like the same interface as Borland Turbo C++ and AFAIR a library was available to enable you to use their tools in your own projects.

Comment: I think that such programs switched to screen mode 3 (`mov ax, 3`, `int 10h`) and then wrote to the display memory (`B800h:0h`) directly. However, I would change the cursor position using `int 10h` instead of writing to the VGA card registers.